# how to get soup.find_all to work in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape information a page consisting names of attorneys using BeaurifulSoup

```
#importing libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

Following is an example of each attorney's names that are nested in HTML tags

```
 </a>
          <div class="person-info search-person-info people-search-person-info">
           <div class="col person-name-position">
            <a href="https://www.foxrothschild.com/richard-s-caputo/">
             Richard S. Caputo
            </a>
```

I tried using the following script to extract the name of each of the attorneys using `'a'` as the tag and "`col person-name-position`" as the class. But it does not seem to work. Instead it prints out an empty list.

```
page=requests.get("https://www.foxrothschild.com/people/?search%5Bname%5D=&search%5Bkeyword%5D=&search%5Boffice%5D=&search%5Bpeople-position%5D=&search%5Bpeople-bar-admission%5D=&search%5Bpeople-language%5D=&search%5Bpeople-school%5D=Villanova+University+School+of+Law&search%5Bpractice-area%5D=") #insert page here
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
find_name=soup.find_all('a',class_='col person-name-position')
print(find_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class="col person-name-position"` is a property of a `div` object, so you need to use:

```
find_name=soup.find_all('div',class_='col person-name-position')
for entry in find_name:
    a_element = entry.find("a")
    #...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your soup.find_all to `div` since the class goes with `div` and not `a`

```
page=requests.get("https://www.foxrothschild.com/people/search%5Bname%5D=&search%5Bkeywod%5D=&search%5Boffice%5D=&search%5Bpeople-position%5D=&search%5Bpeople-bar-admission%5D=&search%5Bpeople-language%5D=&search%5Bpeople-school%5D=Villanova+University+School+of+Law&search%5Bpractice-area%5D=") 
#insert page here
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
find_name=soup.find_all('div',class_='col person-name-position')
print(find_name)
```